# React-google-maps zoom issue

Tags: reactjs, zooming, react-google-maps

I'm using `react.google.maps` and I'm trying to display different markers based on zoom level. The problem I have is that sometimes when I zoom, the map is not updated (the map tiles are not re-rendered based on the zoom level). This happens when I have the `onZoomChanged` method defined. If I remove it, everything works ok.

This is how my class looks like:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.googleMap = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      zoom: 2
    };
  }

  onZoomChanged = () => {
    this.setState({
      zoom: this.googleMap.current.getZoom()
    });
  };

  getMarkers() {
    const { zoom } = this.state;
    let Markers = null;

    // get markers based on zoom

    return Markers;
  }

  render() {
    const { center } = this.props;

    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={2}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: center.latitude,
          lng: center.longitude
        }}
        defaultOptions={{
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
          styles: mapStyles,
          minZoom: 2,
          maxZoom: 10
        }}
        ref={this.googleMap}
        onZoomChanged={this.onZoomChanged}
      >
        {this.getMarkers()}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}
```

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the behavior:

[Actual 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBexB.png)

[Expected 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFqyv.png)

[Actual 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owfrk.png)

[Expected 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vzeM.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...it seems that my issue was related to the center or at least this fixed it:

```
onZoomChanged = () => {
  const newCenter = this.googleMap.current.getCenter();
  this.setState({
    zoom: this.googleMap.current.getZoom(),
    center: {
      latitude: newCenter.lat(),
      longitude: newCenter.lng()
    }
  });
};
```

I also changed the center on `onIdle` method:

```
onIdle = () => {
  const { center } = this.state;
  const newCenter = this.googleMap.current.getCenter();
  const centerLng = newCenter.lng();
  const centerLat = newCenter.lat();

  // other logic for bounds

  if (center.latitude !== centerLat || center.longitude !== centerLng) {
    this.setState({
      center: {
        latitude: centerLat,
        longitude: centerLng
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: HI i have similar issue i want to show different markers based on zoom level tried your example but it's not working.

Comment: @techipank What's the problem ? Can you be more specific ?

I have the following:
- **onZoomChanged** method were I can update the zoom level from the state
- **getMarkers** - were I use the zoom level from the state to get my custom markers based on it.

I need more info in order to help you :)